# How can I completely restore the Ubuntu Files Manager (Nautilus) to default functionality after deleting /var/cache?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, files

I deleted /var/cache thinking it was unimportant because it was a random cache folder. I was wrong, it holds many important configuration files in there, and I assume one of them involved nautilus (FILES). Now I get the following displayed when I click on some directories:

[image]

And the following from `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`:

```
$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/"
```

Comment: You deleted the *folder* `/var/cache` or its *contents*?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it's contents

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity more specifically i ran this command: sudo rm -r * /var/cache/debconf

Comment: I'm afraid you deleted the contents of your home folder... `rm -r *` deletes the contents of the directory you are placed, you meant to do `rm -r /var/cache/debconf/*`. Do an `ls -la` from the terminal and you will see all your folders except the hidden ones disappeared.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity you are completely right, only the hidden ones are present, f*ck

Comment: `sudo rm (-rf)` is always a bad command...